# Indenting issue after access specifiers in Visual Studio Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, indentation, access-specifier

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013

After I use an access specifier, I want Visual Studio to automatically indent my members another 4 spaces further than my access specifier; but instead, it keeps the members in line with the access specifier. Is there a way to fix this?

Example:
This is what is does:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
    int myInt;
};
```

This is what I want:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        int myInt;
};
```

Comment: You and I are the only two people who care about this I think. I don't believe there is a way of doing this automatically except perhaps by creating a vs2013 plugin.

Comment: I have tried to find out how to do it, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Nope, you're not the only ones. :P See my answer!

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to do this in Visual Studio.

However, [a feature request has been made](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/14782797-please-add-an-option-to-auto-indent-the-code-after).

Comment: @Andrew: Your answer wasn't an answer and, as such, was deleted by a moderator. But I have linked to your proposal.

Comment: It was an answer, just not the kind of answer close-minded SO looks for.

Comment: @Andrew: No, it was not.

Comment: "A solution, as to a problem." Yes, it was.

Comment: @Andrew: A link to a page saying "please fix this" is not an answer.

Comment: This is how we get Visual Studio to fix it; therefore, it is a solution and an answer. If you're in a desert looking for water and I point you to the nearest city, I have helped you get water. Am I providing you with the water myself? No, but I couldn't do that anyways.

Comment: @Andrew: On Stack Exchange, it does not count as an answer. Period.

Comment: "just not the kind of answer close-minded SO looks for"

Comment: But please, continue to wallow in wrongness.

Comment: @Andrew: I suggest an attitude adjustment if you intend to survive here.